# conversion from JSON to html tables

Tags: javascript, html, json

i have written a script that will convert json to html tables with simple JSON format (just array and properties) now having an issue with converting the below format. Here, table1, table2, table3 in the code is just the heading(showed in image) and 'name' and 'type' are the properties that will take as column in a table. The images how the output should come.

[image]

```
`{
  "tables": [   
 {
  "name": "table1",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "asset_id",
      "type": "VARCHAR(36)"
    },
    {
      "name": "time",
      "type": "TIMESTAMP"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "table2",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "asset_id",
      "type": "VARCHAR(36)"
    },
    {
      "name": "time",
      "type": "TIMESTAMP"
    },
    {
      "name": "added",
      "type": "BOOLEAN"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "table3",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "asset_id",
      "type": "VARCHAR(36)"
    },
    {
      "name": "time",
      "type": "TIMESTAMP"
    },
    {
      "name": "added",
      "type": "BOOLEAN"
    },
    {
      "name": "enable",
      "type": "BOOLEAN"
    }
  ]
}
]
}`
```

here is my js code

```
function loadJSON(callback) {   
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', 'multiple.json', true); 
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
          callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
  };
  xobj.send(null);  
}

function json2table(tableName, json, classes) {
  var cols = Object.keys(json[1]);

  var headerRow = '';
  var bodyRows = '';

  classes = classes || '';

  function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }

  cols.map(function(col) {
    headerRow += '<th class="th-data">' + capitalizeFirstLetter(col) + '</th>';
  });

  json.map(function(row) {
    bodyRows += '<tr>';

    cols.map(function(colName) {
      bodyRows += '<td>' + row[colName] + '</td>';
    })

    bodyRows += '</tr>';
  });

  tableName = capitalizeFirstLetter(tableName);

  return '<h4>' + tableName + '</h4>' +
        '<table class="' +
        classes +
        '"><thead><tr>' +
        headerRow +
        '</tr></thead><tbody>' +
        bodyRows +
        '</tbody></table>' +
        '<br>';
}

function init() {
  loadJSON(function(response) {
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
    Object.entries(actual_JSON).forEach((item) => $("#tableGoesHere").append(json2table(item[0], item[1], 'table',)));
  });
}

init();
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53149237/edit) then the snippet editor `[<>]` and create a [mcve] and describe expected output. "An issue" does not tell us anything

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
  "tables": [   
 {
  "name": "table1",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "asset_id",
      "type": "VARCHAR(36)"
    },
    {
      "name": "time",
      "type": "TIMESTAMP"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "table2",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "asset_id",
      "type": "VARCHAR(36)"
    },
    {
      "name": "time",
      "type": "TIMESTAMP"
    },
    {
      "name": "added",
      "type": "BOOLEAN"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "table3",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "asset_id",
      "type": "VARCHAR(36)"
    },
    {
      "name": "time",
      "type": "TIMESTAMP"
    },
    {
      "name": "added",
      "type": "BOOLEAN"
    },
    {
      "name": "enable",
      "type": "BOOLEAN"
    }
  ]
}
]
};
```

now get all data with

table name `console.log(data["tables"][0].name)`

name `console.log(data["tables"][0].columns['0'].name)`

type `console.log(data["tables"][0].columns['0'].type)`

change colomn['array value'] and get all